# Spring+Hibernate Unknown column 'users0_.task_id' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate

I'm newbie in Spring and Hibernate. I want create OneToMany relation beetwen two tables User and Task. I think it is stupid mistake in my code but i can't find where. This is my sql code:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tms`.`task` (
  `task_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `hour` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `time` DOUBLE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `task` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`task_id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 4
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4
COLLATE = utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tms`.`user` (
  `user_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `login` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_task`
    FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`)
    REFERENCES `tms`.`task` (`task_id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4
COLLATE = utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

User entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="user_id")
    private int id;

    /* other fields */

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="task_id")
    private Task task;
```

Task entity:

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="task_id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="date") 
    private Date date;

    @Column(name="hour")
    private double hour;

    @Column(name="description")
    private String description;

    @Column(name="time")
    private double time;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="task")
    private List<User> users;
```

I want get from database TASK object with all USER. Can`t understand the field 'users0_.task_id' exist in the database. I think it is default hibernate naming.  Please look at my database because don't have certainty about it.

This is my code which i want fetch data from db:

DAO:

```
@Override
    public Task getTask(int id) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Task task =  session.get(Task.class, id);
        return task;
    }
```

Service:

```
@Transactional
    @Override
    public Task getTask(int id) {
        Task task = userDAO.getTask(id);
        Hibernate.initialize(task.getUsers());
        return task;
    }
```

My controller:

```
Task task = userService.getTask(1);
```

and error:

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'users0_.task_id' in
>   'field list'

Comment: The message says it all: you need a task_id column in the user table to reference the task that the user is assigned to. You currently use the user_if as a foreign key to the task, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks a lot. It's work!